# Trigger.io ToolKit fails to launch properly

Tags: toolkit, trigger.io

I have been experimenting with Trigger.io and was successfully using it last week.

However, I have been trying new stuff out today, and have been unable to open the Trigger Toolkit properly. I'm not sure why - maybe I deleted something by accident.

The error returned was as follows:

```
Error in remote call to app.list: Expecting property name: line 25 column 2 (char 482) Details Close
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/josholdham/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/forge/async.py", line 96, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Users/josholdham/Library/Trigger Toolkit/trigger/api/app.py", line 24, in list
    return forge_tool.singleton.list_local_apps()
File "/Users/josholdham/Library/Trigger Toolkit/trigger/forge_tool.py", line 175, in list_local_apps
    app_config = self._app_config_for_path(path)
File "/Users/josholdham/Library/Trigger Toolkit/trigger/forge_tool.py", line 147, in _app_config_for_path
    app_config = json.load(app_config_file)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    def raw_decode(self, s, idx=0):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 25 column 2 (char 482)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the toolkit a few times, but no joy.

Any help/ advice much appreciated.

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out, I was being a bit stupid:

I had to access hidden files on my Mac to find the Users/josholdham/Library/Trigger Toolkit folder, which I then deleted.

Launching Toolkit again then worked fine.

This is how we find hidden files on the Mac, in case it isn't clear.

http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/

Hope that helps some people - thanks to all previous helpers for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like `src/config.json` is malformed in one of your apps.

I'd recommend looking at `src/config.json` in your apps' directories and checking the JSON syntax around line 25.

In the future, you can avoid these problems by using the App Config tab in the Toolkit to change the config, rather than editing `src/config.json` directly.

Comment: Hey James. Thanks for the help, but I don't think that's the issue. When I load the toolkit, I cannot access my App Directory. I just get a header bar with (Docs Debug etc) and nothing loading in the main section. The file paths specified in the error code don't exist (and they are python references I think, which I don't use), and checking any config files, I don't have a line 25. Also, the whole file looks fine. It's a confusing one....

Comment: @JoshOldham The problem looks like the `src/config.json` for one of the Apps you created or imported in the Toolkit is malformed. The file `/Users/josholdham/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/local_apps.json` has all the folders that the Toolkit tries to load `src/config.json` from, so you should be able to look through those folders and fix the problematic `config.json` file. Looking at the error I suspect the problem is a trailing comma in a JSON object. BTW I think this behaviour is a regression, this failure more isolated to the problematic app in the future.

Comment: Thanks monk. I might be being stupid, but I cannot find that folder in my josholdham directory. I have also tried searching Spotlight for the folders and file but nothing comes up. I could be being an idiot, but I'm not sure...